# Apps Script копирование значения строки в историю на первую пустую строку

Tags: google-apps-script

Всем привет! Нужна помощь в коде...
Есть товары/услуги. По ним ежедневно меняются данные (в примере для этого использована функция СЛУЧМЕЖДУ). На другом листе эти данные перенесены в строку. Необходимо раз в сутки (для этого настроен триггер) переносить данные с этой строки на ближайшую пустую строку, соответствующую дате. Я прописал код в Apps Script, но он переносит на все товары только одно значение. Что я прописал не так? Помогите, люди добрые.

```
    function ProductHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("История данных");
  var value = sheet.getRange('B1:L1').getValues();
  var range = sheet.getRange('B1:L').getValues();
  var lastRow = null;
  var i = 0;
  while(i < range.length) {
    if (range[i][0] !== "") {
      i++;
    } else {
      lastRow = i +1;
      break;
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(`B${lastRow}:L${lastRow}`).setValue(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Последней строкой вы записываете только 1 значение с помощью [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)). А Вам, судя по коду, нужно вставлять диапазон данных. Это делается через [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))